# Google account deleted. Phone number contacts not synchronised. How to get back?

Tags: contacts, google

I accidentally deleted my Google account. After that all my phone numbers saved with Google mail got deleted. Now when I re-added the Google account, though the contacts got synchronized. But phone numbers are not being synchronized back. Where can I find them.

Comment: Do you see the numbers in gmail?

Answer (score 1):

First, go to your Google account and see if contacts are still there. Next, check if your account has contacts sync turned on. To do that go to **Settings/email+accounts/youraccount**, slide down and check if your contacts sync is marked as on.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your account was originally set up long enough ago for Google to support Exchange Sync for you - Google removed support for setting up accounts like this a while back. Recreating the account will have removed the compatibility option, that was allowing it to work previously.

With the forthcoming Windows Phone 8.1, Microsoft have changed the method for syncing with Google, so your contacts will be able to sync again.